# How do I import CSV UUID data into Postgres on the command line?

Tags: postgresql, import, csv, uuid

I'm using PostGres 10.  I have this table

```
> \d myapp_currencyprice;
         Table "public.myapp_currencyprice"
       Column       |           Type           | Modifiers 
--------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id                 | uuid                     | not null
 price              | double precision         | not null
 created            | timestamp with time zone | not null
 currency_id        | uuid                     | not null
```

I have a CSV of data, which looks like

```
id,price,created,currency_id
fa9944a6-f622-499c-89b8-42534a541307,59451.41,2021-11-20 15:56:00-05,3965e495-d5a5-41ec-83fc-359545ca2716
13013751-d84a-441f-a19a-3c7b50c557d0,59474.17,2021-11-20 15:58:00-05,3965e495-d5a5-41ec-83fc-359545ca2716
```

but when I try and import the data on the command line, I get this error

```
> PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASS psql -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME  -c "\copy myapp_currencyprice FROM '/tmp/prices.csv' delimiter ',' csv"
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "id"
CONTEXT:  COPY myapp_currencyprice, line 1, column id: "id"
```

what's the right way to import data from a CSV into a PostGres table?

Comment: I guess you want `header false` or something.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the string "id" is not proper to be a UUID.

Either remove the header line from the file, or tell `\copy` that the file has a header line.

Comment: that is add the keyword "header" after the keyword "csv"